# How to execute multiple inserts when using LIQUIBASE WITHOUT CHANGELOGS

Tags: liquibase

As per [this](http://www.liquibase.org/2015/09/liquibase-without-changelogs.html) documentation

`Liquibase` can execute multiple `sql` files in a given path without the need of any changelogs. However when I created the file with below inserts

```
insert into address (id, line1, line2) values (1, '121 Main Ave', null);
insert into address (id, line1, line2) values (2, '662 Broadway', 'Suite 3317');
insert into address (id, line1, line2) values (3, '412 Riverview', null);
```

I get the following error

> Invalid `sql` syntax

Comment: You always need at least **one** changelog file, which then includes everything else. So how did you include those files in your master changelog?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Liquibase is not recognising your sql file .
Add these 2 lines on top of you sql file :

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset {authorName}:{id}
```

change authorName and id as per your wish . You can also do something like this in your **changelog.xml** file:

```
<changeSet author="authorName" id=”id”>
  <sqlFile path="insertcommands.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

In this case you need not put on top of your **insertcommands.sql** file

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset {authorName}:{id}
```

as you did earlier.

**PS - Tested on liquibase-3.4 and mysql5.5**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But can you tell me why i need to annotate when documentation says liquibase without changelog

Comment: Don't know, may be they forgot to update documentation ...just a guess

Comment: From the page you mentioned in your original question:

"To bootstrap the process, you need a master changelog file that uses the includeAll command. I know the title said “Liquibase Without Changelogs,” but once you have created this file you never have to touch it again."

Also, the thing you linked to was a blog post, and not really 'documentation'.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It helped me resolving my issue.

Answer (score 9):

There are two way to write multiple query

1) using `<sqlFile>` tag.
path : file path where all insert query write

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sqlFile-example"> 
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" path="filepathsql"relativeToChangelogFile="true" splitStatements="true"stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>`
```

Note : required to write attribute splitStatements=true for multiple query execute
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html

2) `<sql>` tag

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">  
    <comment>insert queries</comment>
    <sql dbms="h2, oracle" 
                splitStatements="true"
                stripComments="true">         
        insert into address (id, line1, line2) values (1, "121 Main Ave", null);    
        insert into address (id, line1, line2) values (2, "662 Broadway", "Suite 3317");  
        insert into address (id, line1, line2) values (3, "412 Riverview", null);     
    </sql>    
</changeSet>
```

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html

Comment: thanks for the note on splitStatements, that was my problem!

Answer (score 5):

You may use loadData (or loadUpdate for partial changes in the table) for such purposes:

```
<loadData encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="[path to csv]"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="ADDRESS"/>
```

and provide CSV file with the following contents:

```
id;line1;line2
1;121 Main Ave;null
2;662 Broadway;Suite 3317
3;412 Riverview;null
```